# Is there any way to trace the REST calls that terraform.exe makes to the provider?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am from azurerm provider background and I expect terraform.exe makes Azure ARM REST calls when we call `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`

I know that I can use tools like wireshark to do network tracing, but I expect there should be a more streamlined solution.

Does terraform provide a REST call tracing so I know what exact provider (aws or azurerm) REST API it is using?

Comment: Slight comment on the terminology. "provider" in Terraform parlance is the plugin to Terraform. So "azurerm" is a provider (plugin) to Terraform, which speaks to Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your Terraform with `TF_LOG` environment variable set to `TRACE` (or maybe `DEBUG` is enough?).

In Linux I do:

```
TF_LOG=TRACE terraform apply
```

I guess you are using Windows, so probably something like this would work:

```
set TF_LOG=TRACE
terraform.exe apply
```